# React rendering two p5.js canvases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

I'm trying to use p5.js with react. For some reason, react keeps rendering two canvases. I know this can be solved by turning off StrictMode, but I want to keep the benefits of strict mode while I work on this project. I have tried using a cleanup function, but that doesn't seem to be working either. I'm only using the p5 library, but this still happens even if I use the react-p5 library. Here is my code below.

useP5.js

```js
import p5 from "p5";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function useP5(sketch, dep) {
  const p5ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const instance = new p5(sketch, p5ref.current);
    return instance.remove;
  }, [sketch, dep]);

  return p5ref;
}

export { useP5 };
```

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useP5 } from "./hooks/useP5";

function App() {
  const sketch = (p) => {
    p.setup = () => {
      p.createCanvas(400, 400);
    };

    p.draw = () => {
      p.background(200);
      p.ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);
    };
  };

  const p5Ref = useP5(sketch);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={p5Ref}></div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also included the package.json.

```js
{
  "name": "unending-boundless-dream",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "p5": "^1.7.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The weirdest thing is that I created a stackblitz to replicate the problem. But the stackblitz...doesn't do that. Instead, it only show one canvas.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cafqv9?file=package.json

This is what my result looks like unless I turn off StrictMode.
[image: Double rendering with react and p5]

Comment: What's `counter` defined as, please? Could you try `return () => instance.remove();`?

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry. The counter variable was from when I was trying debug. I have tried `return () => instance.remove()`. It has the same effect as the posted code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem--see my answer, and you're right that it seems OK not to use the arrow function wrapper. Is it possible that `counter` is causing the problem somehow? A [mcve] may be needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sketch` is part of the `useP5` hooks' `useEffect` dependency array, meaning you'll make a new instance of `p5` whenever `sketch` changes.

Because `sketch` is defined as a plain function within the parent component, whenever the parent component is rendered, `sketch` changes and the `useP5` `useEffect` will run.

Now, you do have what appears to be a correct cleanup routine for the `useEffect`. I'm not sure exactly why the cleanup isn't working in certain environments (I can only reproduce this locally using your package.json, and strict mode seems irrelevant; only the forced re-render triggers it for me locally in FF and Chromium). It seems like the the `useEffect`'s cleanup should remove the initial p5 instance.

Possible workarounds:

- Move `sketch` outside of the parent component
- Make `sketch` a ref
- Remove `sketch` from the `useEffect` dependency array in the `useP5` hook
- Memoize `sketch` with `useCallback`: `const sketch = useCallback(p => { ... }, []);`.

Here's the original browser test code, for posterity:

```js
const {StrictMode, useEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

const useP5 = sketch => {
  const p5ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const instance = new p5(sketch, p5ref.current);
    return () => {
      console.log("cleaning up...");
      
      // comment this out to get 2 canvases and 2 draw() loops
      instance.remove();
    };
  }, [sketch]);

  return p5ref;
};

const App = () => {
  const sketch = p => {
    p.setup = () => {
      p.frameRate(1);
      p.createCanvas(400, 400);
    };
    p.draw = () => {
      p.print(p.frameCount);
      p.background(200);
      p.ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);
    };
  };

  ////// Force a second render //////
  const [test, setTest] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setTest("force a second render");
  }, []);
  ///////////////////////////////////
  console.log("rendered");

  const p5Ref = useP5(sketch);
  return (
    <StrictMode>
      <div ref={p5Ref}></div>
    </StrictMode>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.querySelector("#app")
).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

And here's my local test code (in `src/index.js`), with `<div id="app"></div>` in `public/index.html` and your exact package.json:

```js
import p5 from "p5";
import {StrictMode, useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const useP5 = sketch => {
  const p5ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const instance = new p5(sketch, p5ref.current);
    return () => {
      console.log("cleaning up...");
      
      // comment this out to get 2 canvases and 2 draw() loops
      instance.remove();
    };
  }, [sketch]);

  return p5ref;
};

const App = () => {
  const sketch = p => {
    p.setup = () => {
      p.frameRate(1);
      p.createCanvas(400, 400);
    };
    p.draw = () => {
      p.print(p.frameCount);
      p.background(200);
      p.ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);
    };
  };

  ////// Force a second render //////
  const [test, setTest] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setTest("force a second render");
  }, []);
  ///////////////////////////////////
  console.log("rendered");

  const p5Ref = useP5(sketch);
  return (
    <StrictMode>
      <div ref={p5Ref}></div>
    </StrictMode>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.querySelector("#app")
).render(<App />);
```

Looking into it a bit further, it appears that there's a race condition in `.remove()`. If you wrap the state set in the above failing code with a next tick timeout, or wrap the `.remove()` call in a timeout, it seems to clean up as expected:

```js
// works, surprisingly
setTimeout(() => {
  setTest("force a second render");
}, 0);

// also works, surprisingly
return () => {
  console.log("cleaning up...");
  setTimeout(() => instance.remove(), 0);
};
```

I'm sure there's an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: This didn't work for me. And after I made a stackblitz to replicate the problem, I have no idea why. On my computer, in both Chrome and Firefox, it displays two canvases. But on the stackblitz, it only displays one, which makes the whole thing more confusing. I updated the first post with the package.json and stackblitz link.

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce it locally, but not due to `StrictMode`--I can only repro it if I use the `useEffect` in the parent container to trigger a second render. I'm not sure what the cause is, but I've offered a few workarounds.

Comment: Actually, looking into it deeper, I think it's a race condition--if you call `.remove()` on the instance too soon, before it's attached to the ref container element, it doesn't get removed. I'll try to update my answer when I can figure out what's actually going on.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. I'm not sure why it worked, but I'm assuming that creating an instance of a p5 canvas is an asynchronous operation for some reason? Is that it?

Comment: Yeah, canvas creation seems to be async, so calling `.remove()` on the p5 instance too quickly seems to fail since the canvas has not been added as a child yet. I'd like to dig into this deeper but haven't had time yet--I think it'll involve looking at the p5 source. Please keep me posted if you find anything further and I'll do the same.

Comment: You could also memoize `sketch` with a `useCallback`:  `const sketch = React.useCallback((p) => { ... }, []);`

Answer (score 0):

If you wander over here having tried P5 inside your Next.js application, know that your canvas is getting rendered once on the server and once in the client, and there is a special library just for Next: https://github.com/P5-wrapper/next

I also found the code snippet in this comment from @jamesrweb to be very helpful when it came to incorporating props into my sketches. https://github.com/P5-wrapper/react/issues/126#issuecomment-946882884